# How to use data on _trigger for custom widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I have a widget created using jquery ui widget factory. I'm trying to pass some data to my custom event like this

```
this._trigger('myCustomEvent', ['Test', 'Test2']);
```

but on my handler I'm not sure how to access custom parameters

```
onMyCustomEvent: function(event, ui) {
   ...
}
```

I've tried adding parameter to my handler

```
onMyCustomEvent': function(event, ui, param1, param2) {...}
```

but that didn't work: param1 and param2 are `undefined`

Comment: When you tried added the parameters to your handler, did you also make sure you take the additional params out of the array and put them into the proper spots when you attempted to trigger it?

Comment: @Andrew Peacock: I'm afraid I have no idea what you're talking about. What I showed is all the relevant code I have :)

Comment: I tested with a single parameter and didn't work. `this._trigger('myCustomEvent', 'Test');` and `onMyCustomEvent': function(event, ui, param1) {...}``

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide the event param on _trigger. The param can be null.

```
this._trigger('myCustomEvent', null, ['Test', 'Test2']);
```

See: http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#method-_trigger

> Note: When providing data, you must provide all three parameters. If there is no event to pass along, just pass null.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/4Za4m/

```
$.widget( "jsr.exampleWidget", {
    _create: function() {
        this.element.click($.proxy(this._handleClick,this));
    },

    _handleClick: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this._trigger('myCustomEvent', null, ['Test', 'Test2']);
    }    
});

var handleCustomEvent = function(event,param1,param2) {
    alert(param1);
    alert(param2);
};

$("#clickable").exampleWidget({myCustomEvent : handleCustomEvent});
```